# Using Aspx page as a partial view into a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

In my Asp.Net MVC3 project, I have an aspx page called as a partial view into a Razor view.
In the Aspx page i have a button that has to fire an event implemented in the script part.
Here is the code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  %>

<head>
<script runat="server" language="CS">

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //
        //Instructions
        //
    }  

    }

    public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
        //Instructions
        //
    }
</script>
</head>

<form id="frep" runat="server">

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ></asp:Button>

</form>
```

Now, my problem is that the button event does not fire when I click the button ( on the contrary the Page_Load event fire when i refresh the page). I tried several solutions but i don't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You never connect `Button2` with `Button2_Click`. You need to add `OnClick="Button2_Click"` to the button.

And you should also remove those `<head>` tags from around the script - partial views can't have `<head>` tags and runat server code doesn't need to be in them anyway.

Comment: You are right, in this code I forgot to put the OnClick attribute but in my code it exists (OnClick="Button2_Click"), but the problem remains. the head tag doesn't affect anything as i know(i removed it  and nothing changed).